# Google Sheets range(s) to allow varying numbers of checkboxes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, checkbox

I have a sheet where I need to limit the number of checkboxes allowed within a range.  Like this

H219 to H225 allows only one checkbox to be checked.

H228: H335 allows three checkboxes.

H340:H347 Allows two checkboxes.

This script works when I use it once, but when i add it multiple times and change the range it seems to stop working.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='GOALS') {
    const mcpr=1;
    const mcpc=2;
    const arrayrange='h219:h225';
    const arg=sh.getRange(arrayrange);
    const avs=arg.getValues();
    const ulr=arg.getRow();
    const ulc=arg.getColumn();
    const lrr=ulr+arg.getHeight()-1;
    const lrc=ulc+arg.getWidth()-1;   
    if(e.range.columnStart<=lrc && e.range.rowStart<=lrr && e.value=="TRUE") {
      let rc=avs[e.range.rowStart-ulr].filter(function(e){return e;}).reduce(function(a,v){ if(v){return a+1;} },0);
      if(rc>mcpr){e.range.setValue("FALSE");e.source.toast('Sorry maximum checks per row is ' + mcpr);};
      let cc=avs.map(function(r,i){return r[e.range.columnStart-ulc];}).filter(function(e){return e}).reduce(function(a,v){if(v){return a+1;}},0);
      if(cc>mcpc){e.range.setValue('FALSE');e.source.toast('Sorry maximum checks per column is ' + mcpc);};          
    }
  }
}
```

//

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh=e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName()=='GOALS') {
    const mcpr=1;
    const mcpc=3;
    const arrayrange='h236:h244';
    const arg=sh.getRange(arrayrange);
    const avs=arg.getValues();
    const ulr=arg.getRow();
    const ulc=arg.getColumn();
    const lrr=ulr+arg.getHeight()-1;
    const lrc=ulc+arg.getWidth()-1;   
    if(e.range.columnStart<=lrc && e.range.rowStart<=lrr && e.value=="TRUE") {
      let rc=avs[e.range.rowStart-ulr].filter(function(e){return e;}).reduce(function(a,v){ if(v){return a+1;} },0);
      if(rc>mcpr){e.range.setValue("FALSE");e.source.toast('Sorry maximum checks per row is ' + mcpr);};
      let cc=avs.map(function(r,i){return r[e.range.columnStart-ulc];}).filter(function(e){return e}).reduce(function(a,v){if(v){return a+1;}},0);
      if(cc>mcpc){e.range.setValue('FALSE');e.source.toast('Sorry maximum checks per column is ' + mcpc);};          
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you so much, I have searched far and wide and this was the best script i could find, i just need it to work in about 6 places within the same sheet, with each range allowing a different number of checkboxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your current situation and goal as follows.

- You have a Google Spreadsheet that the checkboxes are put to the cells `H219:H225`, `H228:H335` and `H340:H347`.
- You want to give the limitation to the number for checking the checkboxes in each range.
- For example, `H219:H225`, `H228:H335` and `H340:H347` have the limitations of 1, 3 and 2, respectively.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

In this case, in order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose a sample script using an array including the ranges and limitations. The script is run by the OnEdit simple trigger.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet and set the variables of `obj` and `sheetName`, and save it. When you use this script, please check the checkboxes in the ranges `H219:H225`, `H228:H335` and `H340:H347`. By this, the script is run by the simple trigger of OnEdit.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  // Please set the ranges and limitations.
  const obj = [
    {range: "H219:H225", limit: 1},
    {range: "H228:H335", limit: 3},
    {range: "H340:H347", limit: 2},
  ];
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name of the sheet including the checkboxes.
  
  const range = e.range;
  const editedColumn = range.getColumn();
  const editedRow = range.getRow();
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName) return;
  obj.forEach(({range}, i) => {
    const temp = sheet.getRange(range);
    const startRow = temp.getRow();
    const startColumn = temp.getColumn();
    obj[i].startRow = startRow;
    obj[i].endRow = startRow + temp.getNumRows() - 1;
    obj[i].startColumn = startColumn;
    obj[i].endColumn = startColumn + temp.getNumColumns() - 1;
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (editedRow >= obj[i].startRow && editedRow <= obj[i].endRow && editedColumn >= obj[i].startColumn && editedColumn <= obj[i].endColumn) {
      const n = sheet.getRange(obj[i].range).getValues().filter(([h]) => h === true).length;
      if (n == obj[i].limit + 1) {
        range.uncheck();
        // Browser.msgBox("Number of checked checboxes are over the limitation."); // If you want to open the dialog, you canm use this.
      } else if (n > obj[i].limit + 1) {
        Browser.msgBox("Checed checkboxes of existing checkboxes have already been over the limitation number of " + obj[i].limit);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

#### Result:

When above script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- **This sample script is run by the OnEdit simple trigger. So when you directly run the script with the script editor, an error occurs. Please be careful this.**

#### References:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)
- [Event Objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events)

Comment: This works great.  The browser popup doesn't always work but that isn't as important i suppose. Thank you so very much.

Comment: @Brad Singletary Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you could do something like this:
You can add a new section for every range trow is top row, brow is bottom row, lcol is left column and rcol is right column and they are arrays

```
function onEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  const trow = [236];
  const brow = [244];
  const lcol = [8];
  const rcol = [8];
  const mcpr = [1];
  const mcpc = [3];

  if (sh.getName() == 'GOALS' && e.range.columnStart >= lcol[0] && e.range.columnStart <= rcol[0] && e.range.rowStart >= trow[0] && e.range.rowStart <= brow[0] && e.value == 'TRUE') {
    let vs = sh.getRange(trow[0], lcol[0], brow[0] - trow[0] + 1, rcol[0] - lcol[0] + 1).getValues();
    let rc = vs[e.range.rowStart - trow[0]].filter(e =>return e).reduce((a, v) => { if (v) return (a + 1); }, 0);
    if (rc > mcpr[0]) { e.range.setValue("FALSE"); e.source.toast('Sorry maximum checks per row is ' + mcpr[0]); };
    let cc = vs.map((r, i) => { return r[e.range.columnStart - lcol[0]] }).filter(e =>return e;).reduce((a, v) => { if (v) return a + 1; });
    if (cc > mcpc[0]) { e.range.setValue('FALSE'); e.source.toast('Sorry maximum checks per column is ' + mcpc[0]) };

  if (sh.getName() == 'GOALS' && e.range.columnStart >= lcol[1] && e.range.columnStart <= rcol[1] && e.range.rowStart >= trow[1] && e.range.rowStart <= brow[1] && e.value == 'TRUE') {
    let vs = sh.getRange(trow[1], lcol[1], brow[1] - trow[1] + 1, rcol[1] - lcol[1] + 1).getValues();
    let rc = vs[e.range.rowStart - trow[1]].filter(e =>return e).reduce((a, v) => { if (v) return (a + 1); }, 0);
    if (rc > mcpr[1]) { e.range.setValue("FALSE"); e.source.toast('Sorry maximum checks per row is ' + mcpr[1]); };
    let cc = vs.map((r, i) => { return r[e.range.columnStart - lcol[1]] }).filter(e =>return e;).reduce((a, v) => { if (v) return a + 1; });
    if (cc > mcpc[1]) { e.range.setValue('FALSE'); e.source.toast('Sorry maximum checks per column is ' + mcpc[1]) };
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Now that I see Tanaike's I wish I hadn't posted mine.  On the other hand as I look at it close I think this version may have the advantage of using less functions and may perform better.